# After re-initiating the transfer of a same file, why does the portion that was initially transferred get copied very quickly?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, file-transfer, cache

I use Windows 10 on my laptop. I've noticed that if I initiate the transfer of a file, cancel it, then re-initiate the transfer of the same file, the portion that was initially transferred get copied very quickly:

[image]

Why? Is some caching done by Windows 10? by the SSD? something else is happening?

I use a GS76 Stealth 11UH laptop with 2 SSDs mounted with RAID 0.

Comment: I can only assume (thus not an answer) that it is the internal [disk cache](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-caching) mechanism built into windows.  My reason for this *theory* is that the disk cache is at the level of the drivers for the drive and windows tries to cache all reads for subsequent operations by default on supported devices.  To test this theory, try to copy the same 1/2 copied file somewhere else.  :)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.